# I NEED HELP WRITING T SQL

Tags: database, t-sql, loops, cursor

can someone help me write a query that will loop through a table and output the results into a temp table as shown below:

```
  lvl State Program Code

    A   WI  4045      
    B   WI  4045      
    E   WI  4045      
    F   WI  4045      
    I   WI  4045      
    M   WI  4045      
    P   WI  4045      
    R   WI  4045      
    T   WI  4045
```

output

```
Program Code    State   A   E   M   R   T

4053             WI     -   X   -   -   X
```

Comment: I'm going to need more information. Like what are exactly your desired results and what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to **Pivot** the data in your Table. You don't need to Loop through the table.
A simple Group by with Case Statement can do the trick. If you understand basic t-sql, Below query will get you started.

```
SELECT 
[Program Code],[State]
,[A] = MAX( CASE WHEN [lvl]='A' THEN 'X' else '' END)
,[B] = MAX( CASE WHEN [lvl]='B' THEN 'X' else '' END)
,[E] = MAX( CASE WHEN [lvl]='E' THEN 'X' else '' END)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [Program Code],[State]
```

And here is the  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06c75/2)